# Error "xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Image is not a known valid target type for the image property"

Tags: google-rich-snippets-tool, rdfa

I'm trying to test my page with the Google Structured Data Tool, but I run into this problem and I don't understand why.

This is my code (with schema.org):

```html
<article id="node-402" class="node node-blog node-promoted clearfix" about="/blog/cach-lam-mon-bach-tuoc-nuong-sa-te-cuc-ngon-luon" typeof="schema:Recipe">

<span property="schema:name" content="Cách làm món bạch tuộc nướng sa tế cực ngon luôn" class="rdf-meta element-hidden"></span>

<div class="field-item even" rel="schema:image" resource="http://tunghaisan.com/sites/default/files/styles/90x90/public/bach-tuoc-nuong-3-600x372.jpg?itok=iZjw_2S7"><img rel="schema:image" typeof="foaf:Image" src="/sites/default/files/styles/90x90/public/bach-tuoc-nuong-3-600x372.jpg?itok=iZjw_2S7" width="60" height="60" alt="Cách làm món bạch tuộc nướng sa tế cực ngon luôn"></div>

</article>
```

This is the code with image:

```html
<div class="field-item even" rel="schema:image" resource="http://tunghaisan.com/sites/default/files/styles/90x90/public/bach-tuoc-nuong-3-600x372.jpg?itok=iZjw_2S7"><img rel="schema:image" typeof="foaf:Image" src="/sites/default/files/styles/90x90/public/bach-tuoc-nuong-3-600x372.jpg?itok=iZjw_2S7" width="60" height="60" alt="Cách làm món bạch tuộc nướng sa tế cực ngon luôn"></div>
```

And I get error:

> `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Image` is not a known valid target type for the `image` property.

Maybe I did something wrong, do you guys have any idea with this?

Answer (score 3):

Google’s SDTT is intended for checking if the structured data meets the recommendations/requirements for Google’s search features (like rich results). These search features make use of the [vocabulary **Schema.org**](http://schema.org/).

The type `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Image` is from the [vocabulary **FOAF**](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/). This vocabulary is not used by Google for their search features.

So as far as the SDTT is concerned, you are using a property from a known vocabulary (`schema:image`) with a type from an unknown vocabulary (`foaf:Image`). Note that it’s perfectly fine and useful to mix vocabularies, and it should be no problem to keep the unrecognized types and properties in your RDFa (although the SDTT has several related bugs, as least when displaying the output).

If you want one of Google’s search features, you have to use the value which Google expects. For the `schema:image` property, that’s likely the [`schema:ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) type.